# List all elements of a class and store them in an array to set appearance properties in one shot

Tags: arrays, class, swift

Is there a method to list all elements of a kind in a class, store them in an Array and set them grouped styling properties ? For example, I would like to list all text UITextfields in the current class and set the border color, border width, ... I found the very useful code below, but you need to append explicitly each element in the Array.

```
// The extension code 

extension UITextField {
    func setPreferences() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
}

// The following code in the class

var theTextFields = [UITextField]()

func setColorsAndBorders() {

    theTextFields = [tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4] // etc

    for item in theTextFields {
        item.setPreferences()
    }
}

// And the following code in the ViewDidLoad

setColorsAndBorders()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this, assuming your class is a `UIViewController`, while still making use of your extension would be something like:

```
func setColorsAndBorders()
{
    for control in self.view.subviews
    {
        if (control is UITextField)
        {
            let thisControl = control as! UITextField
            thisControl.setPreferences()
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
Another way to do the same thing if you're programatically creating your UITextFields is with this extension:

```
extension UITextField
{
    convenience init(cornerRadius: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat)
    {
        self.init()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
}
```

And then you can, for example, create a text field in such a way:

```
private func loadTextFields()
{
    let thisField = UITextField(cornerRadius: 5, borderColor: UIColor.grayColor(), borderWidth: 1)
    thisField.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height / 2.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 40.0)
    view.addSubview(thisField)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! The code you wrote doesn't work for me. May be it's because my UITextfields are in a Container View Controller. In fact, my View Controller has a Container View Controller and I load a view in this last Container View Controller...

Comment: Ah yes, that'll be the reason.  In this situation you'll need to get a reference to the view you load into the last container view controller.  The best way to do this would probably be to create a `UIViewController` subclass and set the custom class for the Container View Controller to your subclass.  You can then execute this code in that custom class.

Comment: I've just added an alternative method to setting up your `UITextField` controls, which works if you are programatically adding in your `UITextField` controls into that last container view controller.